# Issue in NSUserDefaults LoginView with UISwitch

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I'm unable to store my username and password in `loginView` when I enable `rememberMe` Switch.

Here is my code, Kindly help me!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (rememberSwitch.on == YES){

        self.usernameField.text = usernameField.text;

        self.passwordField.text = passwordField.text ;

    }else{

        NSLog(@"switch is off");

        self.usernameField.text = @"";

        self.passwordField.text = @"";

      }

}

- (IBAction)rememberMeTouched:(id)sender

{

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (rememberSwitch.on == YES) {

        NSString *userString = usernameField.text;

        [userDefaults setObject:userString forKey:@"userString"];

        NSString *passwordString = passwordField.text;

        [userDefaults setObject:passwordString forKey:@"passwordString"];

    }

    [userDefaults setObject:(rememberSwitch.on ? @"true" : @"false") forKey:@"isremember"];

    [userDefaults synchronize];

}
```

Comment: While first view loads your text filed has null value so it will go to display you values. Either you should load values from NS User Default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the content from the NSUserDefault so your code should be like this:

```
if (rememberSwitch.on == YES){

    self.usernameField.text = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"userString"];;

    self.passwordField.text = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"passwordString"];;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue with code

NSString *username = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"userString"]; 
 
NSString *password = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"passwordString"]; 
 
usernameField.text = username; 
 
passwordField.text = password;